# What is the purpose of this hole in cylinder head?

Tags: performance

[image: photo of cylinder head with hole in it]

What is the purpose of this hole in cylinder head bottom?I dismantled cyl.head and change a new one but when I opened the cooling water, water is coming out to this hole.Is there a possibility that the new cyl. head and old cyl. liner has a different measurement? that's why its leaking? Thanks

---

[image]

this is the bottom part of that hole

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! It would surely help us know what's going on if you could please tell us what the vehicle make/model/year/engine is we're looking at.

Comment: Have you checked for a thread? Missing something? Pipe? Blanking screw / plug?

Comment: Looks like a water galley that is missing a plug.  Check your old cylinder head to see if the hole is the same, and if it has anything in it.  Exactly as @SolarMike suggests.

Comment: I checked the old cyl.head same hole no threads or plugs.The model of our auxilliary engine was MAN B&W L16/24.